# Python instance and class namespaces

Tags: python, class, namespaces, instance, scopes

I am new to Python and familiar with Java and C#, so the follow code could be totally un-pythonic.
I'm trying to get an indexed value of an instance of my Class Vector, in which the list of integers it contains is named vec.

```
class Vector:
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if(args and args.length()>=2):
        self.dimension=args[0]
        self.vec=args[1]
    elif(kwargs):
        if(kwargs.get('vec')):
            self.vec=kwargs.get('vec')
            self.dimension=len(self.vec)
        elif(kwargs.get('n')):
            self.dimension=kwargs.get('n')
            nulllist=[]
            for x in range(0,kwargs.get('n')):
                nulllist.append(0)
            self.vec=nulllist

def __getitem__(v,i):
    if(v.vec[i]):
        return v.vec[i]
    else:
        return "None"
```

When I try to get
`v0 = Vector(n=2)
assert(v0[0] == 0)`

I get an assertion Error, because v0[0] returns "None"
If I print(v0[0]) the print output is "None"

What did I do wrong? 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `if(v.vec[i])` - what do you think that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean interpretation of zero is false.  So your `if(v.vec[i]):` will be false if `v.vec[i]` is zero, and the `if` block will not be entered.

It's unclear what you're attempting to test with that `if` anyway.  If you're trying to test whether the element exists, that won't do it.  You might be better off doing something like:

```
try:
    return v.vec[i]
except IndexError:
    return None
```

(Also not sure why you're returning `"None"` instead of `None`, but you can certainly adapt my example to do that if you want.)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize self.vec in the constructor (for the case if and elif are not called).

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.vec = None
        ...


v0 = Vector(n=2)
if v0.vec is not None:
    print('Vector defined')
else:
    print('ERROR: No Vector !')
```